# Rails 4 + Unable to upload the APK file at AWS Server using NGINX

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, file-upload, amazon-s3, paperclip

In my Rails App, I am able to upload the APK file locally and storage place is S3. But the same stuff I tried from AWS server by making the code live. Unable to upload the file.

For Same record, thumbnail and screenshot can be uploaded successfully, but for APK file, it executes the whole process but after page reload, it does not store the record.

I am thinking, some thing is wrong with NGINX setting.
NGINX config file :-

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 768;
  # multi_accept on;
}

http {
##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 600s;
send_timeout 600s;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
client_max_body_size 300M;
client_body_in_file_only clean;
client_body_buffer_size 32K;
# server_tokens off;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# SSL Settings
##

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
# Logging Settings
  ##

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  ##
  # Gzip Settings
  ##

  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";

  # gzip_vary on;
  # gzip_proxied any;
  # gzip_comp_level 6;
  # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  # gzip_http_version 1.1;
  # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

  ##
  # Phusion Passenger config
  ##
  # Uncomment it if you installed passenger or passenger-enterprise
  ##

  passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
  passenger_ruby /usr/bin/passenger_free_ruby;

  ##
  # Virtual Host Configs
  ##

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Not getting the way to resolve it.